# Fill in max by id between two values/date intervals

Tags: r, date, max, dplyr

I need some help with R scripts.

I have a table which looks like this:

```
> dput(first)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1438387200, 1441065600, 1456790400, 
1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 
1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 
1491004800, 1493596800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 
1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1517443200, 1519862400, 
1522540800, 1525132800, 1527811200, 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000, 
1538352000, 1541030400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    ID = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
    "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", 
    "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3"), flag = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -35L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would need to mutate the table such as, if there is less than 5 months from last time when flag ==1 (per each loan) up to when it is 1 again, zeros should be replaced by 1, otherwise to leave it as it is.

Output would look something like this:

```
> dput(second)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1438387200, 1441065600, 1456790400, 
1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 
1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1485907200, 1488326400, 
1491004800, 1493596800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 
1475280000, 1477958400, 1480550400, 1483228800, 1517443200, 1519862400, 
1522540800, 1525132800, 1527811200, 1530403200, 1533081600, 1535760000, 
1538352000, 1541030400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    ID = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", 
    "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", 
    "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", 
    "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3", "A3"), flag = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -35L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Frankly, I don't know where to start, I am kinda new to R.

Comment: I just edited with dput, thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps, try `first %>% filter(as.logical(flag)) %>% group_by(ID) %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(interval(lag(Date, default = first(Date)), Date) %/% months(1) > 5), .add = TRUE) %>% complete(Date = seq(first(Date), last(Date), by = '1 month'), fill = list(flag = 1)) %>% ungroup %>% select(-grp) %>% right_join(first, by = c("ID", "Date")) %>% arrange(ID, Date) %>% transmute(flag = coalesce(flag.x, flag.y))`

Comment: Is there any typo for 'A2' values for flag? i.e. `2017-01-01 A2` in `first` ?

Comment: I meant, it was 0 for the first but I find it to be 1 in second

Comment: yes there is actually, i think your output is correct! thanks a lot!1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `filter` the rows where the 'flag' is 1 from the 'first' data, then grouped by 'ID', create a second group ('grp') based on the difference in months between the adjacent 'Date's, check if it is greater than 5, do the `cumsum` (it increases the group count by 1, whenever the 'Date' difference is greater than 5 months), expand the dataset with `complete` by doing a sequence of 'Date' from the `first` and `last` 'Date' `by` '1 month', join with the original dataset and replace the 'flag' column with `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
first %>% 
     filter(as.logical(flag)) %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     group_by(grp = cumsum(interval(lag(Date, 
       default = first(Date)), Date) %/% months(1) > 5), .add = TRUE) %>%
     complete(Date = seq(first(Date), last(Date), by = '1 month'), 
           fill = list(flag = 1)) %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     select(-grp) %>% 
     right_join(first, by = c("ID", "Date")) %>% 
     arrange(ID, Date) %>% 
     transmute(Date, ID, flag = coalesce(flag.x, flag.y))
```

Comment: Many Thanks akrun for your help. I would have a follow-up question. How do I compute the relative frequency for each month? count(flag==1 per ID)/count(zeros per ID) but only for new flag==1 in each month? Thanks!